# Notification click event in xamarin forms

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to open an `xaml` page when user clicks on the `Notification`. I've searched  but cant find a decent sample for this situation.
By the way I'm using `FCM` with old `GCM` integration.How can I achieve this in android ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to open an xaml page when user clicks on the notification .

When you receive a `Notification` from `FCM`, you could add a `PendingIntent` in `Notification` to implement this function, this will allow the user to open the app. Code like this :

```
void SendNotification(string messageBody)
{
   var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .SetContentText(messageBody)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
```

For more information, you could read the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/#Add_a_Local_Notifications_Sender) and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/Firebase/FCMNotifications/) is the complete code.

Comment: Thanks,I already did this ,but my problem is I want to open an different xaml pages.Your advice is opening the app only ,I mean home page.