# Handle click events on Notification bar that redirects users to the app, Lollipop

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When users click the icon of my app on the Notification bar, users will be redirected to my app.

[image]

Can anyone provide sample code? How to subscribe to the click event, and the redirection.

**Update**

My application might be using some services that cause the display of icon on Notification bar.

My application is calling SetForeground, not getBroadcast().

**Update 2**

how can I redirect users to the last Activity rather than the hard-code activity? For example, the last Activity might be different when users navigate to different activity.

[Notification click event in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206874/notification-click-event-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: What is an answer? What do you want to know?

Comment: sample code on how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

It's a sample from my app, it works. I think you can do somthing similar.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public final static String NOTIF_TEXT =  AlarmSetActivity.class.getPackage() + ".NOTIF_TEXT";

    private String notifText;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        notifText = intent.getExtras().getString(NOTIF_TEXT);
        //().getExtras().getString(NOTE_BODY); 
        Toast.makeText(context, "Notification from " + R.string.app_name,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        buildNotification(context);
    }

    private void buildNotification(Context context) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        String channelId = "default_channel_id";
        String channelDescription = "Default Channel";

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

       Intent intent = new Intent(context, **EditorActivity.class**);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent, 0);

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notificTitle)).setContentText(notifText)
                .setContentInfo(context.getString(R.string.notificInfo)).setTicker(context.getString(R.string.notifTicker))
                .setLights(0xFFFF0000, 500, 500)
                //.setChannelId(id)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        //notification.so

        notificationManager.notify(2, notification);
    }
}
```

And:

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {
    mTimeTextView.setText(R.string.alarm_on);
    mTimeTextView.append(String.valueOf(targetCal.getTime()));

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIF_TEXT,notificationText);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), RQS_TIME, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: how to regist the receiver? my application might be using some services that cause the display of icon on Notification bar.

Comment: Added in answer

Comment: My application is calling SetForeground, not  getBroadcast(). Thus, using broadcast receiver might not work.

Comment: Think, you can try this approach

Comment: how can I redirect users to the last Activity rather than the hard-code activity? For example, the last Activity might be different when users navigate to different activity.

Comment: You can pass Activity.name as a Intent extra, for example. And redirect to this activity.